# Google interactive share

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, google-plus, share

How can I add new line in prefilled text? I tried this code (CoffeeScript)

```
text = '''Line
       New line
       One more line
       '''

        gapi.interactivepost.render(
            'g-share',
            clientid : 'id',
            contenturl: 'url',
            cookiepolicy: 'none',
            prefilltext: text,
            calltoactionlabel: 'JOIN',
            calltoactionurl: 'url'
        )
```

But it's still in one line in Google share window.

Comment: have you tried \n or \r or both \n\r  ?

Comment: Yes, but it's not helped.